# htaccess password multiple password same user

Tags: .htaccess

How to assign **multiple passwords** to the same user in .htaccess password protection?

It looks like this in my .pass file, but only the first one is working

christina:o5hZ6Uplugq.2 
christina:uaZOUG6BzJaUc

Comment: i dont't think you can do that. Single .htpasswd file accepts one user-pass combo. In order to do what you want, you need to have different .htpasswd files, located in different directories

Comment: This would be a good way to rotate a shared password (which is why I Googled the question).

Comment: I think OP clearly demonstrated the required minimal understanding, I believe the closure was a bad decision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can see the source code of the http authenticator in the apache httpd here:

```
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/aaa/mod_auth_basic.c
```

In the function `get_basic_auth()` and in `authenticate_basic_users()` we can clearly see, that the interpretation of the .htaccess file happens in two steps:

1. gets the line of the `.htpasswd` describing the actual user
2. calculates the hash value of the given password and compares this with the htaccess value.

If I interpret the code well, n case of duplicated users, only the first line will have any sense.

Of course you can reach this if you want, but you have to extend this source file a little bit. Or, what is more feasible, you have to use some other type of authentication. For example, an authentication against a database backend may or may not have this additional feature as well. Google for "apache authentication ldap" or some like so, if you wish.